# Installation of Pentaho-Data integration

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

After extracting the Pentaho zip file I downloaded. I set my class path to JDK 1.7.0. But, upon running the Spoon.bat file I keep getting the statement: "Unable to launch your Java Virtual Machine (JVM)." How do I resolve this problem ?

NB: I have configured JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME as stated by similar previously answered questions.

Answer (score 4):

Note that Pentaho7 requires java 8.

In any case, Set the PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=dir, where dir is the directory that contains the  /bin/java.exe executable.

Alternative:
The `spoon.bat` [resp spoon.sh] runs first the `set-pentaho-env.bat` to find a suitable java. Edit this file to know in which order it searches for it. So do like me, when nobody looks at you, edit this file manually, and set `_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME` and `_PENTAHO_JAVA` manually.

To check: In a command line shell, `cd` to your PDI install directory and type `spoon.bat`. It writes something like `start "Spoon" "**some\directory**\javaw.exe" more stuff`. Check that you can type `**some\directory**\javaw.exe -version` in your shell.

If not: in the same directory, type `set-pentaho-env.bat`. It writes down the PENTAHO_JAVA and PENATHO_JAVA_HOME thAt spoon will use. Edit that file until `%PENTAHO_JAVA%\java.exe -version` and `%PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%\java.exe -version` answers the appropriate version.

Comment: Let me know the value of JAVA_HOME which you have set as environmental vatiables.

Comment: JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31"; JRE_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31";

Comment: My JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME and *NOT* set. They should have been set by the java installation. But they were not (because of some reason).

Comment: Nor JAVA_HOME, nor JAVA_JRE are defined as environment variables. They should be set by the java installation process, but were not for some reason (I am not admin on my machine). What matter is PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME and PENTAHO_JAVA: 

I edited my answer for more precision.

Comment: I added more precison. If it does not work, please spacify the PDI version you are using, the java version, and in what directory is the file named javaw.exe.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (for **PDI 9.2.x**), installing an Oracle JDK 8 solved the issue (no need to set the Java home folder explicitly)